# Why is it faster to fetch a resource, create an object URL, and set an iframe's src attribute to that, than to set src to that resource directly?

Tags: javascript, iframe, blob, fetch-api

Recently I was creating a print button for a report. I wanted the print button to use the PDF version of the report for cross-browser consistency. At first I `fetch()`ed the PDF, got the blob, created an object URL, and set the iframes `src` property to that URL.

Later I realized I could just set the iframe`s src to the PDF URL in the first place. But that turned out to be slower by ~400ms on a 5s request. In fact the speed difference seems to scale with the length of the request.

Even when just loading a JSON file, as in the snippet below, the speed difference persists.

Here's a [codepen](https://codepen.io/tvanc/pen/JjmKMJW) where you can fiddle with the tests yourself. I tried re-arranging and adding cache-busting query-string parameter to eliminate that as a possible cause. But `fetch()` is still faster ~90% of the time.

```js
const iframe = document.getElementById("iframe");
const testUri = "https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/topstories.json";
const fastestEl = document.getElementById('fastest')

async function runTests() {
  const srcTime = await measureLoadTimeUsingSrc()
  const fetchTime = await measureLoadTimeUsingFetch()

  document.getElementById("srcTime").textContent = srcTime;
  document.getElementById("fetchTime").textContent = fetchTime;
  
  if (srcTime < fetchTime) {
    fastestEl.textContent = 'src'
  } else if (fetchTime < srcTime) {
    fastestEl.textContent = 'fetch'
  } else {
    fastestEl.textContent = 'tie'
  }
}

function measureLoadTimeUsingSrc() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const startTime = performance.now()
    iframe.src = testUri;
    iframe.addEventListener(
      "load", 
      () => resolve(performance.now() - startTime), 
      { once: true }
    );
  });
}

function measureLoadTimeUsingFetch() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const startTime = performance.now()
    fetch(testUri)
      .then((result) => result.blob())
      .then((blob) => {
        iframe.src = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        iframe.addEventListener(
          "load", 
          () => resolve(performance.now() - startTime), 
          { once: true }
        );
      })
      .finally(() => URL.revokeObjectURL(iframe.src));
  });
}
```

```html
<dl>
  <dt>Time using <code>iframe.src = '…'</code><dt>
  <dd id="srcTime">…</dd>
  <dt>Time using <code>fetch('…')</code><dt>
  <dd id="fetchTime">…</dd>
  <dt>Fastest</dt>
  <dd id="fastest">…</dd>
</dl>

<iframe id="iframe" hidden></iframe>
  
<button type="button" onclick="runTests()">
  Run tests
</button>
```

Comment: I think you're just seeing the cache at work. Try reversing your test order or use different URLs for each

Comment: I tried both with no change to the results. Also, in my real-world use case the URL changed every time, caching was disabled, and each measurement was taken on different page loads, not back to back as in the snippet. I added a link to a codepen with the tests reversed and a cache-busting query string appended to each request.

Comment: Going through profiling im quite sure there is something happening with the request for .src in iframe. I was able to make difrerences to be near 20ms between iframe.src and fetch (added additional iframe, and using unique iframe for each type of request) (also same order or setting the listeners) and it looks like preparing the request for the iframe is a bit longer, maybe because its separating content at that time, while using blob do not execute such restrictions for the context separation between main page and its iframe with different domain request as fetch is not separating it too?